# Execution of Robot Framework tests in Samsung Browser on SauceLabs

Tags: robotframework, samsung-mobile, appium-android, saucelabs

I'd like to configure Robot Framework tests to execute them on Samsung browser in SauceLabs.

I used the config:

```
Open Application    remote_url=${saucelabsUrl}  
        ...    platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}    
        ...    platformVersion=${version_demande}
        ...    deviceOrientation=portrait
        ...    username=XXXX
        ...    accessKey=XXXX
        ...    deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME}    
        ...    app=com.sec.android.app.sbrowser    
        ...    appActivity=com.sec.android.app.sbrowser.SBrowserMainActivity
```

and got an error message: WebDriverException: Message: Verification failed for: com.sec.android.app.sbrowser - Value used is not a valid link. Make sure the link uses http or https format before retrying.

Could you help me with its configuration, please?

Comment: What is the value of variable `${saucelabsUrl}`?

Comment: It's my login + key
https://{Login}:{SauceLabs_Key}@ondemand.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub

Comment: Hmm, looks correct. Just in case be sure, that url starts with 'http...' and there is no, e.g. leading space like ' http...'